# Is it possible to supply an absolute path to hg clone?

Tags: linux, mercurial

All of the examples of `hg clone` that I have seen have used a relative path:

```
hg clone user@example.com/repo
```

This will look up repo in `uers`'s home directory. Is possible to supply an absolute path to `hg clone`?

Comment: I believe you want to provide an absolute path in that an i think it is possible. Please check the "hg help clone". for further details

Answer (score 1):

You can supply an absolute path by using a double slash:

```
hg clone user@example.com//repo
```